# How to cast template class parameter to const parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, casting

is there a way to cast a template parameter type ?

say :

```
#include <list>

class A
{
   int c;
   public:
      A(int a): c(a) {}
};

std::list<const A*> gen()
{
   std::list<A*> list1;
   list1.push_back(new A(5));
   list1.push_back(new A(6));
   return (std::list<const A*>) list1; //Error. Is there a way to cast ?
}

int main()
{

   return 0;
}
```

A reinterpret_cast seems to work with gcc... but the way reiterpret_cast works is compiler-defined... ( ⇒ platform dependent)
(I don't want have to reconstruct another list)

I have to do that because I have a container in a class of object have to modiafiable in the class not outside, but they must still be accessible outside.

Then, what should have been used if say B inherits A, then cast std::list to std::list ?

Comment: Can't you make `list1` of the right type? ` std::list<const A*> list1;`?

Comment: nope, I can't : this was just an example.
of course, I could also remove the const, but it's a compile time security check in less

Comment: If you really need to, you could have `std::list<const A*> list` and then use `const_cast` when you need to modify the `A` pointed to by some element of `list`.

Comment: A better design might be to use a `std::list<A>` instead and make your accessor method return either a copy of the list (which makes a deep copy for you) or a const reference to the list.

Comment: @T.C.: Returning a reference to a local variable is a very bad idea.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Since the OP says what they actually want is "a container in a class of object" that is "modifiable in the class not outside", but still "accessible outside", I assumed the real code does not actually involve a local variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::list<A*>` and `std::list<const A*>` are different types and you cannot cast between them. There are a few options, two of which are:

Use the right type from the beginning:

```
std::list<const A*> list1;
list1.push_back(new A(5));
list1.push_back(new A(6));
return list1;
```

Return an object of the right type, constructed from the original `list1`:

```
std::list<A*> list1;
list1.push_back(new A(5));
list1.push_back(new A(6));
return std::list<const A*>(list1.begin(), list1.end());
```